# No icons on Device Configuration Bar in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, alignment

I have a problem with the `Device Configuration Bar` in Interface Builder in XCode: the device icons don't appear, I can only change the view orientation - see attached image. Also, I searched everything, and still can't find how to attach that part of the bar to the menu. Any ideas?

View orientation instead of the alignment menu:

[image: View orientation instead of the alignment menu]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by tapping on the words "View as: iPhone SE" which made the devices appear below.

Answer (score 0):

Open Xcode preferences and click the "Components" button.  That should list all the simulators you have installed.  Click the "Check and Install Now" button to update.  Also make sure the the "Check for and install simulator and documentation updates automatically" button is checked.